# Websocket or ajax long polling or ajax short polling with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, websocket

I have a page where when a user clicks on a button ( Pay ) , a popup opens with banks page..my server waits for the response from the bank, so that i can close the pop up and show the response to the user without reloading the page.

Practically I can use Ajax long/short polling or server sent events. But performance wise using polling with PHP is not recommended. I can expect a traffic of around 1000 people using that page. Approximately 1000 req/sec which can go up as my system and user base scales.

Now I am really confused how do I implement this push notification of the status to my user without changing my current PHP/Apache backend. I will be using polling only at this place and this is not similar to chat also. A user get a notification once and its done.

I am not able to find a perfect stack which can use with PHP without screwing up my server processes.

**will be adding bounty of 150 as this suggestion is very critical for me**

Comment: If it's just a single request per user, why would you need polling? Just make an AJAX request - assuming the payment gateway supports it.

Comment: No The payment gateway is redirection based. When user clicks pay, the bank page opens in a pop up. when bank authorizes, they sent me a server to server call. which inturn ill have to show up on the users payment  page with status. So the request is not  a single once. A user will have to know the status once, Thats what i was saying

Comment: why not use server-sent events?

Comment: take a look at http://razorpay.com/demo you will be able to see what I am trying to do

Comment: @madalinivascu It supports only few browsers. is there any performance issue if I use it with PHP?

Comment: @Ajeesh from what i can tell no, you can do a combination of server-sent and ajax for the browser that don't have this capability

Comment: @Ajeesh if you don't want to mess arround with other language then best option is Websockets, as what I know is TCP handles connection which is combination of ip and port, so using websocket will solve your 70% of the problem. If you still want high capability then I suggest you to use nodejs